# List Intersection

Tags: delphi, list, intersection

I want to compute a list "intersection". The problem is:

```
L1 = [1, 0, 2, 3, 1 , 3, 0, 5]
L2 = [3, 5]
```

Then the result will be

```
L3 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Then i will convert this result in a byte.  In this case will be 21 in decimal format.

I want to make in delphi and I need this do efficiently.  Is there a way to solve this problem better than O(m*n)?

Comment: If the result will always fit in a byte, then we can assume `m = 8`, right? Are there upper bounds on the values stored in L2? (In particular, could they always be between 0 and 255 inclusive?)

Comment: I also don't understand what you mean by intersection. With your data my guess is that L3 = [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0]. Did you make a mistake?

Comment: My structure is a Array of Byte. L1 with N elements and L2 with M elements. THe intersection will be O(M*N).

Comment: If i find a L2 element in L1 the output element will be 1 else 0.
I find the element '3' or '5' in the position represented by the L3.
Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: @David: It appears that, for any n-component vector ('list') A and m-component vector ('list') B, the intersection of A and B is an n-component vector C where, for every i = 1, 2, ..., n, C_i is equal to one if B_j = A_i for some j = 1, 2, ..., m, and zero otherwise.

Comment: You can sort the second (shorter) array first to implement "intersection" algorithm faster than N*M

Comment: Database Designer: Are you asking about TLIST, ARRAY, or SET? None of these is exactly like a Python-style 'LIST'.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function that should do what you want. I defined `L2` as a set instead of an array since you said all your values will fit in a `Byte`. Its complexity is O(n); checking set membership runs in constant time. But since the result needs to fit in a byte, the length of `L1` must be bound at 8, so the complexity of this function is actually O(1).

```
function ArrayMembersInSet(const L1: array of Byte; const L2: set of Byte): Byte;
var
  i: Integer;
  b: Byte;
begin
  Assert(Length(L1) <= 8,
    'List is to long to fit in result');
  Result := 0;
  for i := 0 to High(L1) do begin
    b := L1[i];
    if b in L2 then
      Result := Result or (1 shl (7 - i));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I will try this code! Thanks! Do you know  if the operator IN is O(N)?

Comment: `in` is O(1) as stated in the answer, "checking set membership runs in constant time"

Comment: you may as well write your for loop from 0 since your shift operation assumes that. You could assert that and that the array has no more than 8 elements.

Comment: I am curious. How the operator IN work? Does it use a Hash to make the operation in O(1)?

Comment: It works by doing bitwise operations. A set is, internally, an array of up to 32 bytes. The program uses the magnitude of the left operand to decide which byte to check, and then does a simple "and" operation.

Comment: You're right, @David. I usually assume the lower bound of an open our dynamic array is zero, but then people complain about not using `Low`, so I made that last-minute change before posting my answer.

Comment: it directly addresses and tests the bit in the bitset. For a `set of byte`, the compiler allocates 256 bits (that is 32 bytes of 8 bits).

Comment: @Database, you accepted my answer earlier, but not anymore. Can you tell me what additional information you're hoping for?

Answer (score 2):

Rob's answer will work for this specific case.  For a more general case where two lists have to be compared, you can do it in O(m+n) time if both lists are sorted.  (Or O(n log n) time if you have to sort them first, but that's still a lot faster than O(m*n).)

The basic List Comparison algorithm looks like this:

```
procedure ListCompare(list1, list2: TWhateverList; [Add extra params here]);
var
  i, j: integer;
begin
  i := 0;
  j := 0;
  while (i < list1.Count) and (j < list2.Count) do
  begin
    if list1[i] < list2[j] then
    begin
      //handle this appropriately
      inc(i);
    end
    else if list1[i] > list2[j] then
    begin
      //handle this appropriately
      inc(j);
    end
    else //both elements are equal
    begin
      //handle this appropriately
      inc(i);
      inc(j);
    end;
  end;

  //optional cleanup, if needed:
  while (i < list1.Count) do
  begin
    //handle this appropriately
    inc(i);
  end;
  while (j < list2.Count) do
  begin
    //handle this appropriately
    inc(j);
  end;
end;
```

This can be customized for a whole bunch of tasks, including list intersection, by changing the "handle this appropriately" places, and it's guaranteed to not run for more steps than are in both lists put together.  For list intersection, have the equals case add the value to some output and the other two do nothing but advance the counters, and you can leave off the optional cleanup.

One way to use this algorithm is to make the extra params at the top into function pointers and pass in routines that will handle the appropriate cases, or nil to do nothing.  (Just make sure you check for nil before invoking them if you go that route!)  That way you only have to write the basic code once.

Answer (score 0):

Well no matter what you will need to visit each element in each list comparing the values.  A nested loop would accomplish this in O(n^2) and the conversion should just be local work.

EDIT: I noticed that you want a better runtime than O(n*m).

Comment: Why do you need to do it in a nested loop?

Comment: How else would you compare each element in each list.

Comment: The answer that is O(1) uses a SET and an ARRAY, and no LISTS.