# Find common elements in two Integer List

Tags: list, delphi, integer

I have two given `integer` List:

```
alist  : TList<Integer>;   //  eg.   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
blist  : TList<Integer>;   //  e.g   1,2,3,4,5

Resultlist  : TList<Integer>;     

IgnoreList : TList<Integer>;   //  e,g,  1,2,3
```

What is a effective way to find the common elements on both lists, excluding elements from the ignore list. As I have to run this procedure over many items I need a effective and fast way of implementation for this problem.

```
Resultlist  should be 4,5
```

Comment: In your example, the lists are sorted. In real life, will your lists always be sorted? If so, the implementation is much easier.

Comment: You can convert your Lists into HashSet's and find an Intersection

Comment: the list are not sorted, what is the Hashset ?

Comment: Do you have a lower and upper bound for the possible values?

Comment: If the lists are short then straight linear compare all with all is fastest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List Intersection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099899/list-intersection)

Comment: This might be a time to bring up the sad fact that this would be a quick one-line operation if Delphi sets weren't crippled by being restricted to bytes.

Comment: @alcalde what does your set of Integer implementation look like?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In ISO Pascal it would be ResultSet := aset * bset - IgnoreSet; This works in GNU Pascal.

Comment: @alcalde I asked about the implementation

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Dmitry. Converting lists to hash sets and looking up in them would be fast irrespective of whether the lists are sorted.

Have a look at Delphi's TDictionary. TDictionary intersection is one quick way of finding common elements. Otherwise,

1) Create a TDictionary for blacklisted elements.
2) Create a TDictionary and insert elements from alist that are not present in blacklist-dictionary. This operation is fast because TDictionary are optimized for lookup.
3) finally, iterate over elements of blist and only output elements preent in alist-dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

What you want for this is the [list comparison algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6102623/32914).  You take two sorted lists (make sure to sort them first if they aren't already) and two index variables, set both indices to 0, and start comparing values, advancing one index or the other if they aren't equal, or both indices of they are.  By customizing the behavior of the algorithm when unequal or equal values are found, there are a lot of things you can do with this.  What you want for here is, when equal values are found, insert the value into the output list.

Comment: Isn't the question therefore a dupe? Sorting is poor. Problem is O(n)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The problem is only O(n) if the lists are sorted; otherwise it's O(N^2).  Since sorting is O(n log n), it's the best way to go.

Comment: O(N) for unsorted. Use a dictionary.