# understanding TDictionary on IntegerList

Tags: delphi

can I create a TDictionary directly on a TList class ? It looks a bit double work if I create my TDictionary Class with key and values are always the same data  like BlackList.Add(1, 1);

```
var
  BlackList: TDictionary<Integer, Integer>;
  ResultList: TDictionary<Integer, Integer>;
  TestListA: TLIst<Integer>;
  TestListB: TLIst<Integer>;
  i: Integer;
begin
  BlackList.Add(1, 1);
  BlackList.Add(2, 2);

  for i := 0 to TestListA.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if BlackList.ContainsValue(TestListA[i]) then
    begin
      // no action ...
    end
    else
    begin
      ResultList.Add(i, TestListA[i]);
    end;
  end;

  for i := 0 to TestListB.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if BlackList.ContainsValue(TestListB[i]) then
    begin
      // no action ...
    end
    else
    begin
      if not(ResultList.ContainsValue(TestListB[i])) then
        ResultList.Add(i, TestListB[i]);

    end;
  end;
end;
```

The purpose of this algorithm is to compare 2 Integer list's , find all doubles but exclude numbers from a blacklist. The first q is here [Find common elements in two Integer List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21500360/find-common-elements-in-two-integer-list).

Comment: There is no need of a dictionary here. `TList<T>.Contains` will do the same job than `TDictionary<T>.ContainsValue`

Comment: @SirRufo, that's right, but I think OP wanted to use `TDictionary<T>.ContainsKey` instead, otherwise the use of a dictionary would lose it's sense in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole purpose, in this particular code, of using `TDictionary` is to take advantage of O(1) lookup. With `TList`, which is an array, you do not have that property. Lookup is O(n) in general, O(log n) if sorted. So you cannot extract the O(1) lookup performance from a `TList` by any means, hence the use of `TDictionary`.

So it is the performance motivation that is driving the use of `TDictionary`. As I said in your previous question, the overhead of setting up dictionaries is only worthwhile if the lists are large. You would need to do some benchmarking to quantify what large means in this context.

As for your dictionary, it does not matter what values you use since only the keys are significant. So use zero always. Ideally what you want is a hash set type based on the same algorithm as the dictionary. But I don't believe there is such a thing in the stock RTL. I expect that libraries like Spring4D offer that functionality.